# Eclipse 4.18.0 Unable to open marketplace - NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I'm not able to open eclipse marketplace because I get the following exception. Any advice a part from reinstalling from scatch ?

Marketplace Client  1.9.0.v20201125-0811

eclipse.buildId=4.18.0.I20201202-1800 java.fullversion=11.0.10+9 JRE 11 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20210120_910 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) OpenJ9   - 345e1b09e OMR      - 741e94ea8 JCL      - 0a86953833 based on jdk-11.0.10+9 BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui.CatalogDescriptor.imageDescriptorForUrl(CatalogDescriptor.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui.CatalogDescriptor.<init>(CatalogDescriptor.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.installRemoteCatalogs(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.createConfiguration(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand.createConfiguration(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.lambda$2(AbstractContributionItem.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem$$Lambda$435/0x0000000000000000.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5785)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1427)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5048)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4526)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$$Lambda$210/0x0000000000000000.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)
```

Previous warning is:

*Failed to retrieve catalog image for Eclipse Marketplace from http://marketplace.eclipse.org/sites/default/files/eclipse-catalog.png*

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.installRemoteCatalogs(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.createConfiguration(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand.createConfiguration(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.lambda$2(AbstractContributionItem.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem$$Lambda$435/0x0000000000000000.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5785)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1427)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5048)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4526)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$$Lambda$210/0x0000000000000000.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)
```

Comment: Does updating the Marketplace client via _Help > Install New Software..._ as follows fix your issue? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569861#c4

Answer (score 1):

That looks like [**Eclipse bug 569861**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569861) that has **already** been **fixed**.

The patch of this

- will be in the upcoming [Eclipse Marketplace Client (MPC) **1.9.1**](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.packaging.mpc/releases/1.9.1) (which will be released on March 17, 2021) and
- is already in the preview build that can be installed via *Help > Install New Software...* and the update site [**`http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/drops/1.9.0/v20210108-0835/`**](http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/drops/1.9.0/v20210108-0835/) (see [comment by Leif Geiger](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569861#c4)).